# Different types of vipassana meditation?

Tags: theravada, personal-practice, reference-request, meditation, the-buddha

I am interested in vipassana meditation.

**What are the different types of vipassana meditation?**

Comment: Why is he changing the question entirely after getting answers?

Comment: @Letsbuddhism The previous question was closed as being opinion-based. He modified it then it was reopened.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing called Vipassana Jhanas in the suttas. But in the commentaries there is something called Lakkhaṇūpanijjhāna.

Tattha lakkhaṇūpanijjhānaṃ nāma vipassanāmaggaphalāni.

Therein, lakkhaṇūpanijjhāna is the name of insight, path, and fruit.

> Vipassanā hi tīṇi lakkhaṇāni upanijjhāyatīti lakkhaṇūpanijjhānaṃ.
>
> Insight meditates upon the three characteristics, therefore it is
> meditation on characteristics.
>
> Maggo vipassanāya āgatakiccaṃ sādhetīti lakkhaṇūpanijjhānaṃ.
>
> The path completes the task begun by insight, therefore it is
> meditation on characteristics.
>
> Phalaṃ tathalakkhaṇaṃ nirodhasaccaṃ upanijjhāyatīti
> lakkhaṇūpanijjhānaṃ.
>
> Fruition meditates on the characteristic of reality that is the truth
> of cessation, therefore it is meditation on characteristics.